# An example on Stack implementation I tried to solve

Tags: c

I am trying to practice an example on stack, and I am finding a bit difficulty in printing the answer of this example.

```
/* A letter means push and an asterisk means pop in the
    following sequence.  Give the sequence of values returned by the pop operations
    when this sequence of operations is performed on an initially empty LIFO stack.

     E A S * Y * Q U E * * * S T * * * I O * N * * *
*/
#include<stdio.h>

char a[40] = "EAS*Y*QUE***ST***IO*N***", s[20], b[30];
int top = -1;
```

This one is the PUSH operation.

```
void push(char a)
{
  int i=0;
  if (top >= 24)
    printf("Overflow.");
  else if (a == '*')
    b[i++] = pop();
  else
    s[++top]= a;
}
```

And this is the POP operation.

```
 void pop()
 {
    if (top < 0)
      printf("Underflow");
    else
      top--;

    return s[top+1];
 }
```

And the main function.

```
void main()
{
  int i;
  printf("%s\n", a);

  for (i=0; i<24; i++)
    push(a[i]);

  for (i=0; i<24; i++)
    printf("%c", b[i]);
}
```

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: I can't get to print the array b[] , i ran it on codeblocks and it just showed me a blank screen

Comment: Did you try to debug your code?

Comment: It isn't letting me to debug the code

Comment: I'm sorry but i'm a bit new at all this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your push function, you are declaring `int i` as a local variable. With this in mind, can you see how your line `b[i++]=pop();` will always evaluate to `b[0]=pop();`?

Edit:
Here are the suggested changes. Per Tim's suggestion, you should make `int i` a `static` variable.

```
void push(char a)
{
static int i=0;
    if(top>=24)
        printf("Overflow.");
    else if(a=='*')
        b[i++]=pop();
    else
        s[++top]=a;
}
```

You also need to make `pop` return a `char` instead of `void`

```
char pop()
 {
    if(top<0)
       printf("Underflow");
    else
       top--;

   return s[top+1];
 }
```

[jdoodle](https://jdoodle.com/a/MB2)

Comment: Ok Then what should I be using instead the above problem

Comment: They're a few ways you could do it. The most obvious to me would be to use a new global variable similar to `int top`. Then you would use it just like `top` in your `push` function and get rid of `int i`. Let me know if you can get this working.

Comment: The most obvious to me would be to make `i` a `static` variable. It would keep its value from one function call to the next, but be hidden (protected) from the rest of the code.

Comment: This is what I get.    UnderflowUnderflow       ?        ?

Comment: @DeepMevada have you tried Tim's suggestion? His is better than mine.

Comment: That is what's in my original code I have used `int i=0` in the push function which means it is a static variable for push function.

Comment: Static variables require the `static` keyword, try `static int i=0`

Comment: Nope still not working , the output is just a bunch of ? in square boxes ( i don't know what that is).

Comment: There is an error saying conflicting types for 'pop' .

Comment: Check my edit. You may have forget to change the return type for `pop`